# Losing some z3c relation data on restart

Tags: plone, dexterity

I have the following code which is meant to programmatically assign relation values to a custom content type.

```
publications = # some data

catalog = getToolByName(context, 'portal_catalog')
for pub in publications:
  if pub['custom_id']:
    results = catalog(custom_id=pub['custom_id'])
    if len(results) == 1:
      obj = results[0].getObject()
      measures = []
      for m in pub['measure']:
        if m in context.objectIds():
          m_id = intids.getId(context[m])
          relation = RelationValue(m_id)
          measures.append(relation)
      obj.measures = measures
      obj.reindexObject()
      notify(ObjectModifiedEvent(obj))
```

Snippet of schema for custom content type

```
measures = RelationList(
  title=_(u'Measure(s)'),
  required=False,
  value_type=RelationChoice(title=_(u'Measure'),
                            source=ObjPathSourceBinder(object_provides='foo.bar.interfaces.measure.IMeasure')),
  )
```

When I run my script everything looks good. The problem is when my template for the custom content tries to call "pub/from_object/absolute_url" the value is blank - only after a restart. Interestingly, I can get other attributes of pub/from_object after a restart, just not it's URL.

Comment: How do you run the script? Something like "bin/instance run script.py"? Then you need to commit the changes.The attribut `from_object` is there, even if you have nothing stored.

Comment: @Mathias it's in a BrowserView which should handle commits, but I did try adding transaction.commit() and it doesn't make a difference. And to clarify, I can do pub/from_object/Title and it works, I just can't get pub/from_object/absolute_url. It's like it loses its context on restart.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`from_object` retrieves the referencing object from the relation catalog, but doesn't put the object back in its proper Acquisition chain. See http://docs.plone.org/external/plone.app.dexterity/docs/advanced/references.html#back-references for a way to do it that should work.

Comment: Actually plone.app.relationfield monkey patches RelationValue.from_object to make it do that automatically, so I'm not sure why that isn't working for you. Maybe that monkey patch isn't getting loaded for some reason?

Comment: I have to use Plone 4.1 for this project which has a version of plone.app.relationfield from being the monkey patch was added. The doc you referenced provided a working solution though, thanks!